# CSS-Grid frozen column implementation issues with scrolling

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a table with frozen columns using CSS-grid.
What I've did is to make a main grid that contains left and right subgrids, while the right subgrid has overflow scroll properties when view is resized to smaller width.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  width: max-content;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--ncols),max-content);
  grid-auto-rows: 24px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.frozen-scroll {
  width: auto;
}

.frozen-static {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.grid-container-frozen {
  display: grid;
  width: auto;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.item {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-left: 1px solid #8080804a;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8080804a;
}

.spanned {
  grid-row-end: span var(--rowspan);
  grid-column-end: span var(--colspan);  
}

.table-header {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-image:linear-gradient(#D1DFF1, #8EA9CC);;
  color: #000;   
  justify-content: center;
}

.column-item {
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #e4e4e4);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container-frozen">
  <div style="--ncols:1;" class="grid-container frozen-static">
    <div class="item table-header"><span></span></div>
    <div style="--rowspan:1;--colspan:1;" class="item column-item spanned"><span></span></div>
    <div class="item column-item"><span></span></div><div class="item"><span>TextTextTextTextTextText</span></div>
  </div>
<div style="--ncols:8;" class="grid-container frozen-scroll">
  <div class="item table-header"><span>Table Header</span></div>
      <div style="--rowspan:1;--colspan:4;" class="item column-item spanned"><span>Column0</span></div>
      <div style="--rowspan:1;--colspan:4;" class="item column-item spanned"><span>Column1</span></div>
      <div class="item column-item"><span>Type A</span></div>
      <div class="item column-item"><span>Type B</span></div>
      <div class="item column-item"><span>Type C</span></div>
      <div class="item column-item"><span>Type D</span></div>
      <div class="item column-item"><span>Type A</span></div>
      <div class="item column-item"><span>Type B</span></div>
      <div class="item column-item"><span>Type C</span></div>
      <div class="item column-item"><span>Type D</span></div>
      <div class="item"><span>0</span></div>
      <div class="item"><span>0</span></div>
      <div class="item"><span>0</span></div>
      <div class="item"><span>0</span></div>
      <div class="item"><span>0</span></div>
      <div class="item"><span>0</span></div>
      <div class="item"><span>0</span></div>
      <div class="item"><span>0</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Weird things I've noticed:

1. The right subgrid still spans full-width when when the parent width is set to auto. If `grid-container-frozen` width property changed to `max-content`, I no longer get the scrolling when resizing, why is that? I want a frozen left column with the rest of the columns with scrolling ability (if bigger than view)
2. I set left and bottom borders on each cell, but rightmost border is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the borders, but I think you're needing to use [`minmax(max-content, auto)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax) to achieve the scrolling you're after.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  width: max-content;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--ncols), minmax(max-content, auto));
  grid-auto-rows: 24px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.frozen-scroll {
  width: auto;
}

.frozen-static {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.grid-container-frozen {
  display: grid;
  width: auto;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.item {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-left: 1px solid #8080804a;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8080804a;
}

.spanned {
  grid-row-end: span var(--rowspan);
  grid-column-end: span var(--colspan);  
}

.table-header {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-image:linear-gradient(#D1DFF1, #8EA9CC);;
  color: #000;   
  justify-content: center;
}

.column-item {
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #e4e4e4);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container-frozen">
  <div style="--ncols:1;" class="grid-container frozen-static">
    <div class="item table-header"><span></span></div>
    <div style="--rowspan:1;--colspan:1;" class="item column-item spanned"><span></span></div>
    <div class="item column-item"><span></span></div><div class="item"><span>TextTextTextTextTextText</span></div>
  </div>
<div style="--ncols:8;" class="grid-container frozen-scroll">
  <div class="item table-header"><span>Table Header</span></div>
      <div style="--rowspan:1;--colspan:4;" class="item column-item spanned"><span>Column0</span></div>
      <div style="--rowspan:1;--colspan:4;" class="item column-item spanned"><span>Column1</span></div>
      <div class="item column-item"><span>Type A</span></div>
      <div class="item column-item"><span>Type B</span></div>
      <div class="item column-item"><span>Type C</span></div>
      <div class="item column-item"><span>Type D</span></div>
      <div class="item column-item"><span>Type A</span></div>
      <div class="item column-item"><span>Type B</span></div>
      <div class="item column-item"><span>Type C</span></div>
      <div class="item column-item"><span>Type D</span></div>
      <div class="item"><span>0</span></div>
      <div class="item"><span>0</span></div>
      <div class="item"><span>0</span></div>
      <div class="item"><span>0</span></div>
      <div class="item"><span>0</span></div>
      <div class="item"><span>0</span></div>
      <div class="item"><span>0</span></div>
      <div class="item"><span>0</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This disables the column width-to-content functionality I'm after, any workaround for this?

Comment: @susdu Not sure what you mean by "width-to-content" functionality.  The width of the right (`.frozen-scroll`) grid either adapts to [the widest its content will allow before needing to scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLx9l.png) or [it fills the rest of the grid width expanding as needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjffB.png).  Those images illustrate what I'm seeing.  Are you seeing something different?

Comment: I was referring to the former, your solution disables that

Comment: @susdu Those two screen caps are of the same code.  The only difference is I changed the browser window width.  That's how `minmax()` works.  It calculates a value that is greater than or equal to min and less than or equal to max. What browser and operating system are you testing this on?

Comment: sorry I misunderstood, I think I get you now. What I want is fitting the grid to the content (like in my example with max-content, but with scrolling when content is too big for the view, due to resizing etc.)